# BigQuery ML - Linear Regressor Training Stopping After One Iteration

Tags: machine-learning, google-bigquery

I'm training a linear regressor in BigQuery. I'm training it with ~20000 rows of data and a target output column with values in `{0, 1}`. I'm setting the `EARLY_STOP` option to `False`. I have set the `MAX_ITERATIONS` option to `10`. My training always stops at 1 iteration with an MAE of ~0.2. Here is the create model query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL `sketching.linear_regressor_08-13--11-59-03.811249`
OPTIONS (model_type=@model_type, 
input_label_cols=@input_label_cols, 
max_iterations=@max_iterations, 
data_split_method=@data_split_method, 
early_stop=@early_stop) AS
SELECT * FROM `ds.training_table`
```

These are the parameters in the query (python object print):

```
[ScalarQueryParameter('model_type', 'STRING', 'linear_reg'),
ArrayQueryParameter('input_label_cols', 'STRING', ['target_output']),
ScalarQueryParameter('max_iterations', 'INT64', 10),
ScalarQueryParameter('data_split_method', 'STRING', 'RANDOM'),
ScalarQueryParameter('early_stop', 'BOOL', False)]
```

PS: I've inspected `bytes_processed` of the `QueryJob`. It checks out (meaning that it is actually processing the whole table.

#### UPDATE

It looks like BQ is ignoring most of the model options that is supplied. This is a screenshot of my model status on the bigquery web api:
[image]

As you can see in the **training options** section, it is showing none of the options that I provided and that options that are displayed are actually not provided. I changed the **data split method** option and it did affect a change here.

#### UPDATE 2

I provided the `L1_REG` (`0.1`) option and it magically fixed the problem. Training went up to 10 iterations (the `max_iterations` provided).
If I run the model without any optional options (or just the `early_stop` option) it stops at `1` iteration.

Comment: I wouldn't expect linear regression to take multiple iterations if it's just OLS - do you have reason to believe this should take more than one iteration? Once you introduce a regularization term like L1 (LASSO) or L2 (Ridge Regression), or both (Elastic Net), then it's more reasonable to take more iterations.

Also, this is more of a theory question that might be more appropriate to the Data Science stack exchange. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yeah you're right. I assumed it was a bug, but I think it's expected behaviour from _lin reg_. That said the __training options__ console doesn't look right.

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your model is probably stopping because the least square solution is being directly computed. This is due to the fact that the default setting for `OPTIMIZE_STRATEGY='AUTO_STRATEGY'` and your query doesn't fulfill the requirements for batch gradient descent to be selected over the direct least square solution.[1]

If you don't want this to occur, set `OPTIMIZE_STRATEGY='BATCH_GRADIENT_DESCENT'`

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create-glm#optimize_strategy